# log the mongoose queries for a request-response cycle in express

Tags: express, mongoose, logging, middleware, winston

I am trying to log the queries getting executed on the mongoose connection in one express request.

```
export default (req, res, next) => {
  mongoose.set("debug", (collectionName, methodName, ...methodArgs) => {
    const id = req.requestId;
    Logger.info({
      label: "Mongoose",
      requestId: id,
      message: `${collectionName}.${methodName}(${methodArgs,join()})`,
    });
  });
  next();
}
```

the above middleware prints the unique requestId, during which the mongoose query is executed for one request at a time.

But, when there are multiple concurrent requests to the server, i.e. while the first request is still running, second request is also made. Due to this the mongo queries running for the 1st request also prints the Id of the second request. because the id in the mongoose.set('debug') gets overwritten.

how can i write this, such that even if there are multiple concurrent requests, the mongoose logger gets access to the requestId of which it is part of.

Comment: You can't. Mongoose only has one debugger function, so concurrent requests (as you've seen) will overwrite each other.

Comment: is there some other way? What should I change to make this logging possible?